# NM linux command output meaning

Tags: linux, static-libraries, symbols, static-linking, nm

I'am searching a specific symbol in my lib:

```
nm --undefined-only -A libcpprest.a | grep "error_category"
```

and I obtain:

```
libcpprest.a:json.cpp.o:          U _ZNSt14error_categoryC2Ev
libcpprest.a:json.cpp.o:          U _ZNSt14error_categoryD2Ev
libcpprest.a:json.cpp.o:          U _ZTISt14error_category
```

what's meaning "**_ZNSt14**" and "**C2Ev**"?

Is there a way to clean nm output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ compilers perform [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) to support features like function overloading (using the same function name multiple times with different signatures, accepting different arguments).  Different compilers may use different conventions for their name mangling.

You can use the [c++filt](https://linux.die.net/man/1/c++filt) utility to demangle the names into a more readable form.  In your case:

```
> c++filt -n _ZNSt14error_categoryC2Ev
std::error_category::error_category()

> c++filt -n _ZNSt14error_categoryD2Ev
std::error_category::~error_category()

> c++filt -n _ZTISt14error_category
typeinfo for std::error_category
```

This is 3 different symbols containing the name "error_category": a constructor, a destructor and type information.

Answer (score 2):

It's also possible to demangle symbol names by passing "--demangle" flag to nm command [[1]](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html#:%7E:text=%2D%2Ddemangle%5B%3Dstyle%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Decode,demangling%20style%20for%20your%20compiler.:%7E:text=%2DC%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2D%2D-,demangle,-%5B%3Dstyle%5D.).

```
nm --demangle --undefined-only -A libcpprest.a | grep "error_category"
```